# How can I do calls to the server whilst the user is typing in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have seen these websites that do checks to the DB on the fly. For example I'm typing in my username and and i'm typing its checking to see if it is valid or is already in the DB. Does anyone know where I can find an add-on or tutorial that will do this for me?

Comment: why did they change my question?

Comment: Your original title didn't describe the question. You can't get much more vague then *Javascript or Jquery help* for a title. I should be able to read your title to get a summary of your question.

Comment: thought that i put more than that but thx thats all i needed to know

Answer (score 3):

- `keyup` event and maybe a `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 500);` to POST the string via XHR
- Look up in database if the username exists, and return either `true` or `false`.
- If `false` received via XHR, add error message and prevent submitting of form.

[jsFiddle of more than enough to get started](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RqDqm/).

Comment: so what your saying is you don't have an answer?

Comment: @Rod The outline above describes what you need to do. You can either get full working code and not understand it (that won't help you) or you can put some effort in and Google the functions and terms I have listed, learn something yourself and become a better programmer. You won't improve being spoonfed answers especially if you say you have little to no experience.

Comment: @Rod Nelson: SO does *not* exist to spoon feed you. If you're not willing to learn, this is probably not the best place for you.

Comment: i am willing to learn it  was just the way he said it. second i learn better by seeing examples not just a vague idea

Comment: @Rod What was wrong with the way I said it? It seemed your first comment was either deleted or flagged enough for its removal.

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

**Edit**: Hmm, either I misread your question earlier, or the edit changed your question a bit...but my above suggestion is not quite what you're looking for. Check [alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346659/how-can-i-do-calls-to-the-server-whilst-the-user-is-typing-in-javascript-or-jquer/5346691#5346691)

Answer (score 0):

http://choosedaily.com/1308/15-jquery-autocomplete-plugins-tutorials/

or

http://www.nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/

same idea - simpler handling

Comment: don't see how an auto completer is the solution?